# Google Play Developer suggest Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, google-play

I have a little problem with my app on google play, it say to me optimise your app for the tablet in the advice tabs but in my app I have already implement the muti pane layout, and I have the different folder for layout(sw600dp, sw720dp).

I also added this line to my manifest

```
 <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I also added image for the 7-inch and 10-inch tablet.

I don´t understand why I already have this advice, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add images of the tablet layout under the "Store Listing" section within the your Developer Console.

[image: Example in Dev Console]

Comment: I am also added images for 7 and 10 inch tablet